# JQuery flip plugin and animation queueing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of tiles on my website http://zhickman.com/.

Ideally, when you slide your mouse over all the tiles, I want the tiles to flip and revert on their own. I've run into issues where, when using the hover event, sliding over the tiles just makes them flip once. Then, when hovering over the tiles individually, hover events happen over and over again with the flip animation, instead of staying still. So, I added a boolean to not flip until the handlerOut for hover is called. This works when using tiles individually, but if you move the mouse out before the animation is done, the tile remains the same.

I want to use queueing, but in using the global fx queue, adding tile flip and revertflip animations would cause tiles to wait on other tiles to finish their animation.

I got partial functionality using stops:

```
var test = false;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".box").hover(function(){
            if (test == false) {
                $(this).stop(false, true).flip({speed: 350, direction:'lr', color:'#c5cac6', content:$(this).children('.info').text()})
                test = true;
            }
        }, function(){
            $(this).stop(false, true).revertFlip();
            test = false;
        });
    });
```

But this breaks the original flipping animation, as seen on the website linked.

My question is:

1) Can I use animation queueing for this, and what's the proper way to do it?
2) Is there an easier alternative (am I just using stops incorrectly)?

Comment: Have you considered css animation? This would avoid the need for any JavaScript at all. Would you accept an answer based on css animation?

Comment: I looked into CSS animation (http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) but it caused issues with my existing CSS, which gave dynamic resizing boxes. If you can propose a solution which meshes well with the resizing functionality I have right now, then yes, that would be perfectly acceptable!

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ If possible, can post included `html`, `css`, `js` ? Thanks

Comment: If I was going to spend a lot of time getting this right, I would be spending it getting david walsh's css animations working. They will be hardware accelerated and if you compare them at least in chrome, they look a lot smoother and nicer than those javascript flip animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are using seems that does not apply any CSS styles, it appends some div elements that I think that are really a mess.

I have implemented your CSS and HTML in a CSS only approach.

My main goal was to use as less additional styles and elements as possible. So in your demo you have to un-nest the `.info` and `.box` elements and wrap them around with a `.flipper` div.

Your block structure will look like this

```
<a href="resume.pdf">
        <div class="flipbox-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                <div class="box resume"><span class="box-header">Résumé</span><br /><br />

                </div>
                <div id="resume-info" class="info">
                        My current résumé. Contains technical skills, employment history, and education history.
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
```

Take a look at the full functional demo I have made http://jsfiddle.net/NSUq5/1/

Keep in mind that I haven't changed any of your original styles. The code that generates the animation is at the very bottom of the CSS panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `onBefore` callback you should be able to use to stop any previous animations.

Like this:

```
$(this).flip({
    speed: 350, 
    direction:'lr', 
    color:'#c5cac6', 
    content:$(this).children('.info').text(),
    onBefore: function(){
         /*
            do stop here-->
            $(this).stop(args);
         */
     },
});
```

What you are doing with your `test` boolean may work better if you set it in the `onAnimating` and `onEnd` callback functions of the plugin.